# При нажатии на кнопку не срабатывает callback

Tags: javascript

Есть форма и функция валидации. При подтверждении формы срабатывает `onclick="validation_form"` и выводится окошко с сообщением об успешной отправке формы. В этом окошке кнопка "ОК". По нажатии на неё это окошко должно исчезать и заново появиться форма. Окошко это выводится, а вот обратно при нажатии на "ОК" не закрывается. Клик как бы отрабатывается `console.log()` работает. Но вот нужного результата нет.

Код:

```js
function validation_form() {
  if (($('#feedback input[name="name"] value') !== '') &&
    ($('#feedback input[name="mail"] value') !== '') &&
    ($('#feedback textarea') !== '')) {

    $(this).click(function() {
      $('#feedback form').hide();
      $('#feedback-message').show();
    });
  }
}

$('.ok-btn').click(function() {
  $('#feedback form').show();
  $('#feedback-message').hide();
  console.log('ok-btn pressed');
});
```

```html
<div id="feedback">
  <h1>Обратная связь</h1>
  <div class="white-border"></div>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите имя..." required>
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Введите эл. почту..." required>
    <textarea cols="38" rows="6" name="message" placeholder="Введите сообщение..." required></textarea>
    <img src="../assets/img/reCAPTCHA.png" alt="reCAPTCHA" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="orange-btn" onclick="validation_form()">
      <p style="margin: 0;">Отправить</p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="feedback-message">
    <img src="../assets/img/success-icon.png" alt="success">
    <div class="text-message">
      <p class="green-text">Сообщение успешно отправлено!</p>
      <p>Спасибо за Ваше обращение.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="ok-btn">
      <p class="green-text">Ок</p>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавьте в сниппет необходимую разметку, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему. Но могу предположить, что вы вместо вызова обработчика, навешиваете еще один, и должно было быть `$(this).click()`

Comment: Рекомендую проверить все селекторы на правильность. А вообще да, добавьте разметку.

Comment: добавил разметку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция обратного вызова отлично работает при клике на кнопку, да и вызовы `show` и `hide` *каждый раз* отрабатывают нормально.

**Что происходит на самом деле?**

Когда вы вызываете функцию в отрыве от контекста, переменная `this` ссылается на глобальный объект `window`. (Кстати, это происходит только вне [строгого режима](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).) Как следствие, в функции `validation_form` вы привязываете скрытие формы на клик по **окну**.

Когда вы кликаете по кнопке `.ok-btn` форма снова показывается, **но** событие продолжает всплывать по дереву DOM пока не дойдет до объекта `window`. А к нему на событие `click` подвязано сокрытие формы.

В итоге, форма показывается и сразу же скрывается. Аналогичная картина наблюдается и для элемента `#feedback-message`.

**Что делать?**

Вам не нужно привязывать вызовы `hide` и `show` в функции `validation_form` к клику. Это не имеет смысла. А если вы все-таки хотите использовать событие `click` используйте осмысленный объект, а не `this`.

Правильный код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
function validation_form() {
    if (($('#feedback input[name="name"] value') !== '') &&
            ($('#feedback input[name="mail"] value') !== '') &&
            ($('#feedback textarea') !== '')) {
        $('#feedback form').hide();
        $('#feedback-message').show();
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLc96eLL/)

**Замечание:**

Условие в конструкции `if` не имеет смысла. Совсем. Но с этой проблемой я предлагаю вам разобраться самостоятельно ;-)